# Multiple account for contacts Sync in Whatsapp

Tags: contacts, sync, google-contacts

I have multiple accounts in contacts Gmail, Phone, Samsung account.
Which account will it take to sync with Whatsapp ?
What is the limit of contacts ?
As per my work i have total 50k plus contacts in my phone in various accounts, will it sync in whatsapp ?
I have tried all possible ways to sync account deletion, reset of my phone, restarting phones.
I can see few contact names in whatsapp but in my contacts when i open the app of contacts there is no link to whatsapp in none of the names.